# Dictionaries Within Pandas Dataframe Columns in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a CSV that has a column called 'location' of dictionaries such as the following.

```
{"city": "Bellevue", "country": "United States", "address2": "Ste 2A - 178", "state": "WA", "postal_code": "98005", "address1": "677 120th Ave NE"}

{"city": "Atlanto", "country": "United States", "address2": "Ste A-200", "state": "GA", "postal_code": "30319", "address1": "4062 Peachtree Rd NE"}

{"city": "Suffield", "state": "CT", "postal_code": "06078", "country": "United States"}

{"city": "Nashville", "state": "TN", "country": "United States", "postal_code": "37219", "address1": "424 Church St"}
```

I'm looking to read the CSV into a dataframe, and then parse out city, state, street, zip, country into their own columns.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Load the column into a list and create a new dataframe.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

column = [{"city": "Bellevue", "country": "United States", "address2": "Ste 2A - 178", "state": "WA", "postal_code": "98005", "address1": "677 120th Ave NE"},
          {"city": "Atlanto", "country": "United States", "address2": "Ste A-200", "state": "GA", "postal_code": "30319", "address1": "4062 Peachtree Rd NE"},
          {"city": "Suffield", "state": "CT", "postal_code": "06078", "country": "United States"},
          {"city": "Nashville", "state": "TN", "country": "United States", "postal_code": "37219", "address1": "424 Church St"}]


df = pd.DataFrame(column)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        city        country      address2 state postal_code              address1
0   Bellevue  United States  Ste 2A - 178    WA       98005      677 120th Ave NE
1    Atlanto  United States     Ste A-200    GA       30319  4062 Peachtree Rd NE
2   Suffield  United States           NaN    CT       06078                   NaN
3  Nashville  United States           NaN    TN       37219         424 Church St
```

---

EDIT: To read from csv file, you can use this example:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

data = []
with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_in:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(literal_eval(row[0]))  # <-- here i use [0], beacuse the dictionary is in column 0

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Comment: I'm reading this from a CSV - how would I put the column into a list?